# how to update yml created entities, if they are expanded with business logic?

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity

when you execute doctrine:generate:entities with a set of yml files containing your relation mapping, all Entity classes are automatically generated.

When you adjust your yml files and regenerate the Entity classes, they are overwritten (and the old ones are backed up).

In doctrine1, the entity-generator created Base Classes that where automatically inherited by the actual Entity Class, that you could expand with your own business logic.

In doctrine2 I don't see those base classes, and I don't want to adjust my generated classes, because i won't be able to update my datamodel in my yml files.

What is the Doctrine2 approach?
Should i manually inherit from my generated Entity Classes to add business logic?
Can doctrine adjust the Entity class, and keeping the additional changes (with some sort of diffing algorithm)?
Does the entity-generation only be used once to generate the classes, and should all the datamodel changes be implemented manually in the Class itself?

Answer (score 1):

In Doctrine2 you program your entities as you wish (with respective fields, getters and setters, custom business logic, etc.), and then create the yaml (or xml, annotations, etc.) mappings. What Doctrine2 then generates are the DB tables which correspond to your mappings, so your entities are always preserved.

I suggest you take a look at the [Doctrine2 Quick Start Guide](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/tutorials/getting-started-xml-edition.html), it will give a pretty good idea of the Doctrine2 ORM approach.

Comment: I want my yaml files to be the starting point. I use ORM Designer (http://www.orm-designer.com/) to model my datamodel. I can export ORM Designer files to the appropriate yaml files and use doctrine:generate:entities to generate my Entity Files. Is this approach not supported by Doctrine2? Seems a bit weird to me, since doctrine:generate:entities would be obsolete and the yaml (or xml, annotations) would only be there for reference?

Comment: It is supported. In that case use the doctrine tool with orm:generate-entities parameter, which generates entity classes and method stubs from your mapping information. So, I guess each time you do this, the old entities are overwritten; you can avoid this by putting your custom model/entity logic in a subclass of the generated class, so when you generate entity classes, your custom code is not overwritten. Take a look at Doctrine2 tool reference: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html

Comment: Ok, i can extend my generated and automatically updated classes to preserve my business logic. How can i tell symfony to use these extended classes instead of those in the Entity/ folder?

Comment: Well, I'm not a Symfony expert, I'm sorry :(